# How to abandon or deadletter messages on ServiceBus BrokeredMessage level on AzureFunction V2?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I am encountering one major road block issue when trying to use ServiceBusTrigger in azureFunction. I am trying to abandon, or deadletter, a service bus message in V2 ServiceBusTrigger, How can I do so? I've tried the following solution, but I didn't get anywhere. 
Here is the codeSample I used:

```
public async static Task Run(Message myQueueItem, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
{
   log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message delivery count: {myQueueItem.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount}");

   QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient("[connectionstring]","[queueName]");

   ////await queueClient.DeadLetterAsync(myQueueItem.SystemProperties.LockToken);
   await queueClient.AbandonAsync(myQueueItem.SystemProperties.LockToken);
 }
```

Solution 1: I tried to substitute Message myQueueItem  for BrokeredMessage like in V1, I then can call myQueueItem.Abandon, or deadletter, on the message lever. However It came back with exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'. System.Private.DataContractSerialization: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage. The input source is not correctly formatted. System.Private.DataContractSerialization: The input source is not correctly formatted."

At least I can go one step further. to 
solution 2. Solution 2: is to use:

```
 QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient("[connectionstring]","[queueName]");      
 ////await queueClient.DeadLetterAsync(myQueueItem.SystemProperties.LockToken);
 await queueClient.AbandonAsync(myQueueItem.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

I can use the lock provided in the Message Object, however, when I try to send it with queueClient, It said the message gone from the queue. or no longer available.

Can anybody let me know if i am on the right track? If I am not, please kindly guide me in the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus messages are automatically completed or abandoned by Azure Functions runtime based on the success/failure of the function call, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior):

> The Functions runtime receives a message in PeekLock mode. It calls Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls Abandon if the function fails.

So, the suggested way to `Abandon` your message is to throw an exception from function invocation.

Comment: Thanks for the for reply. @Mikhail. However, I tried to throw an exception in the azure function to force exception to happen. however it still said function completed and the message is gone from the queue.

Comment: Is it not in DLQ?

Comment: @mslugx do you have the solution? I am running into the same issue

Comment: @HungCao The issue is fixed, and it does abandon messages, and requeue the message automatically for processing. You might want to upgrade azure functions SDK to the newest version.